# Activation value at output neuron equals 1, and the network doesn't learn anything

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, c++

I'm implementing a typical neural network with 1 hidden layer. The network does well with the logic XOR and other simple problems, but fails miserably when encountering a (16-input, 20~30 hidden, 3 output) training set. The problem is that the network does not learn anything, even with learning rate = 1.0 and momentum 0.8 ~ 0.9.

I did a lot of debug and found that at some output, the activation value is 1.0, even though mathematically the result of the logistic function (1/(1+exp(-signal)) can not be 1, but due to rounding, the computer produces 1.0 for signal that is >40.

Now, with the activation value equals 1.0, the gradient is always 0 regardless of the desired output because the term `(1-activation)` will be 0, so in the equation:

```
delta = (1-activation) * (activation) * (activation - desired_output)
```

delta will be zero all the time, so no learning at all.

I tried to initialize the weights at very small value (0.00001 or so) but eventually all of them reach 3.0 ~4.0, or even some extreme value like 30~40, so with 20~30 hidden neurons it's very easy to end up with output signal >40.

Obviously I must have missed something, but with this kind of neural net (with hundreds of weights) I can't debug it too see what's wrong, so my question is: do all of the above symptoms signal anything wrong with my code?

Here are some important code:

```
class NNWeight {
    double ** weights;
    double *bias;
}
double sigmoid(double value) {
    return 1.0/(1.0+exp(-value));
    }
double Dsigmoid(double value){  //gradient
    return value*(1-value);
}
    //wInpHid = input-to-hidden layer weights (of type NNWeight)
    //wHidOut = hidden-to-output layer weights (of type NNWeight)

    void updateWeight() {
    for (int iInp = 0; iInp<nInp; iInp++)
        for (int iHid = 0; iHid<nHid; iHid++)
            wInpHid.weights[iInp][iHid] += dInpHid.weights[iInp][iHid];
    for (int iHid = 0; iHid<nHid; iHid++) {
        wInpHid.bias[iHid] += dInpHid.bias[iHid];
    }
    for (int iHid = 0; iHid<nHid; iHid++)
        for (int iOut = 0; iOut<nOut; iOut++)
            wHidOut.weights[iHid][iOut] += dHidOut.weights[iHid][iOut];
    for (int iOut = 0; iOut<nOut; iOut++)
        wHidOut.bias[iOut] += dHidOut.bias[iOut];
}
void feedFW() {
    bool correct = true;
    // Feed the hidden layer
    for (int iHid = 0; iHid<nHid; iHid++) {
        hid[iHid] = wInpHid.bias[iHid];
        for (int iInp = 0; iInp<nInp; iInp++) {
            hid[iHid] += inp[iInp] * wInpHid.weights[iInp][iHid];
        }
        hid[iHid] = sigmoid(hid[iHid]);
    }
    //Feed the output layer
    for (int iOut = 0; iOut<nOut; iOut++){
        out[iOut] = wHidOut.bias[iOut];
        for(int iHid = 0; iHid < nHid; iHid++)
            out[iOut] += hid[iHid]*wHidOut.weights[iHid][iOut];

        out[iOut] = sigmoid(out[iOut]);
    }
}
void backProp() {
    double SE =0.0;
    //Calc the output errors:
    for (int iOut = 0; iOut<nOut; iOut++){
        SE += (out[iOut] - tar[iOut])*(out[iOut] - tar[iOut]);
        outErr[iOut] = (tar[iOut] - out[iOut]) * Dsigmoid(out[iOut]);
    }
    //Calc the hidden errors:
    for (int iHid = 0; iHid<nHid; iHid++){
        double sum_wHidOut = 0.0;
        for (int iOut = 0; iOut<nOut; iOut++) {
            sum_wHidOut += outErr[iOut]*wHidOut.weights[iHid][iOut];
        }
        hidErr[iHid] = sum_wHidOut * Dsigmoid(hid[iHid]);
    }
    //Calc hidden - output layer delta (dHidOut)
    for (int iHid = 0; iHid<nHid; iHid++)
        for(int iOut = 0; iOut<nOut; iOut++){
            dHidOut.weights[iHid][iOut] = lRate * outErr[iOut] * hid[iHid] + dHidOut.weights[iHid][iOut] * momentum; //lRate = learning rate
        }
    for (int iOut = 0; iOut<nOut; iOut++){
        dHidOut.bias[iOut] = lRate * outErr[iOut] + dHidOut.bias[iOut] * momentum;
    }
    //Calc input - hidden layer delta (dInpHid)
    for (int iInp = 0; iInp<nInp; iInp++)
        for (int iHid = 0; iHid<nHid; iHid++)
            dInpHid.weights[iInp][iHid] = lRate * hidErr[iHid] * inp[iInp] + dInpHid.weights[iInp][iHid] * momentum;
    for (int iHid = 0; iHid<nHid; iHid++)
        dInpHid.bias[iHid] = lRate * hidErr[iHid] + dInpHid.bias[iHid] * momentum;
            //Update the weights
    updateWeight();
}
```

Comment: You should try to add a regularization term to avoid your weight to be too big

Comment: That's a first step but that is usually not the problem. At the moment I cannot find an error in the code. It is really strange that the activations become so big. Maybe there is a problem with your data? Do you have an unequal class distribution, e.g. 90% of your data are 1?

Comment: @alfa I normalize all inputs so that they sum to 1, but with some weights as big as 40, (and there're 16 input, 32 hidden neurons), I guess normalization is not at all helpful.

Comment: That's an unusual normalization for inputs, usually you substract the mean and devide by standard deviation or range of the data. However, have 50% of your training data the label 1 and 50% the label 0 or is there an unequal distribution, e.g. 90% 1 and 10% 0. In this case neural networks sometimes tend to predict everything as 1.